# Writing MPEG 4 headers

Tags: mpeg, mpeg-4

I have a Hardware which encodes YUV frames into MPEG-4 frames.

I want to save these frames as a MP4 movie, but I can't find any article or document to explain how to do it.

I found an open source project (I don't remember from where) it encodes to MPEG-4 and it has the atom of MPEG-4 with it. so I have the body of MPEG-4 but I don't know how to use It.

any Advice or Help would be really useful.

Comment: You have an elementary stream and you need to multiplex it into a file. This leads you to certain tools or libraries, which in turn are specific to environment you did not specify. Or, you certainly can implement yourself checking MPEG-4 Parts 12, 14 specification.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [MP4Box](http://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/) and it's core library libgpac. It's been around as long as MPEG-4, and it's main function (amongst many, many others) is packaging (multiplexing) raw MPEG-4 audio and video streams in MPEG-4 containers.